# Import xml namespace from custom Dataweave module

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I'm trying to create a custom Dataweave module for centralizing my custom XML namespaces.

I followed the official document of Mulesoft:https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-create-module

it states that: "When you import a custom module into another DataWeave script, any functions, variables, types, and namespaces defined in the module become available for use in the DataWeave body".

So I was expecting that I could create a module (in modules folder) containing my namespaces like this: Namespaces.dwl

```
ns myNs1 http://namespaces/my1
ns myNs2 http://namespaces/my2
```

import that module in another Dataweave like this:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from modules::Namespaces
output application/java
---
{
    body: {
        myNs1#Response: {
            outcome: 'ACCEPTED'
        }
    } write "application/xml"
}
```

But I got this **error:**

**The prefix myNs1 has not been previously declared using ns**

I'm running on Mule 4.3.0

Comment: It looks like a bug or the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: @aled, any solution for this? can you suggest anything? or I should raise a support case with Mulesfot

Comment: I can't see any alternatives. I recommend to report this behavior as a possible but, including the details from the question so it can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As aled have pointed out, it might have been a bug or incorrect information in the docs. From what I can see, the namespaces are properly imported but it seems that prefixes are expected to be declared locally.

You can use below:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from modules::Namespaces
output application/java

var myNs1Local = myNs1 as Namespace

---
{

    body: {
        myNs1Local#Response: {
            outcome: 'ACCEPTED'
        }
    } write "application/xml"
}
```

which will result to the expected output.

```
{
  body: "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<myNs1:Response xmlns:myNs1=\"http://namespaces/my1\">\n  <outcome>ACCEPTED</outcome>\n</myNs1:Response>" as String {class: "java.lang.String"}
} as Object {encoding: "UTF-8", mediaType: "*/*", mimeType: "*/*", class: "java.util.LinkedHashMap"}
```

Notice here that what I used as the prefix is the declared variable (myNs1Local) but it still write the prefix as referenced in Namespace.dwl

Answer (score 0):

Tried this with
With Mule 4
Runtime 4.4.0

**It worked without any issues.**

Created a custom module and declared namespaces and imported it into my dataweave worked without declaring prefixes again in the local dataweave.

Created below module under the folder **src/main/resources/modules**

**Namespaces.dwl**

```
ns myNs1 http://namespaces/my1
ns myNs2 http://namespaces/my2
```

**Dataweave :**

```
%dw 2.0
import * from modules::Namespaces
output application/java
---
{
    body: {
        myNs1#Response: {
            outcome: 'ACCEPTED'
        }
    } write "application/xml"
}
```