# "mulexml:namespace-manager" not resolving, showing unknown

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, cloudhub

I am trying to declare few XML namespaces globally in a Mule 4 application, using "mulexml:namespace-manager".

https://docs.mulesoft.com/xml-module/0.3.9/xml-namespaces

But the element "mulexml:namespace-manager" not resolving, showing as "unknown" and build is failing.

Can anyone let me know what dependency needed to be added from the exchange to work with this? Tried few things and tried to get details from MuleSoft documentation, but no luck.

Comment: You need to provide more details so others can help you. Share the file that is giving the error. What is the version of Mule? How are you building the application? If with Maven you should share the pom.xml. Share the exact and complete error. Read how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question to add the details. Kindly avoid to use comments to add the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a Mule 3 feature in Mule 4 but that feature is not supported in the newer version. Using DataWeave modules to share namespace declarations for DataWeave scripts is the alternative way that is compatible with Mule 4.

Note that CloudHub is only where you deploy the Mule 4 application so it is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Thank you. I tried creating a custom module and declared namespaces and imported it into my dataweave, but it seems that prefixes are expected to be declared locally. (the issue is discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514220/import-xml-namespace-from-custom-dataweave-module )

Is there anyway to avoid it?