# Is there any way to centralize the custom XML namespaces in Mule 4 application?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

**Application and runtime version:** Mule 4 application, with XML Module.

I'm trying to create mule application with many custom xml namespaces. It seems that prefixes are expected to be declared locally, like this,

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns orders http://www.acme.com/shemas/Orders
ns stores http://www.acme.com/shemas/Stores
---
root:
    orders#orders: {
        stores#shipNodeId: "SF01",
        stores#shipNodeId @(shipsVia:"LA01"): "NY03"
    }
```

**Is there any way to centralize the custom XML namespaces?**

---

**1.**
Tried something in this :
[Import xml namespace from custom Dataweave module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514220/import-xml-namespace-from-custom-dataweave-module)

I tried creating a custom module and declared namespaces and imported it into my dataweave, but it seems that prefixes are expected to be declared locally

**Namespaces.dwl**

```
ns myNs1 http://namespaces/my1
ns myNs2 http://namespaces/my2
```

**Dataweave :**

```
%dw 2.0
import * from modules::Namespaces
output application/java
---
{
    body: {
        myNs1#Response: {
            outcome: 'ACCEPTED'
        }
    } write "application/xml"
}
```

**But this doesn't work**,  again this requires declaring prefixes locally, something like this. After declaring prefixes locally this works.

```
%dw 2.0
import * from modules::Namespaces
output application/java

var myNs1Local = myNs1 as Namespace

---
{

    body: {
        myNs1Local#Response: {
            outcome: 'ACCEPTED'
        }
    } write "application/xml"
}
```

**After declaring prefixes locally this works.**

---

**2.**
I tried to understand namespace-directory documented here:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/xml-module/latest/xml-xpath

The documentation explains how to use this with Xpaths, **but Not sure how to use this while creating XML, couldn't find any documentation**.

```
<xml-module:namespace-directory name="fullNs"> 
    <xml-module:namespaces>
        <xml-module:namespace prefix="soap" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
        <xml-module:namespace prefix="mule" uri="http://simple.component.mule.org/"/>
    </xml-module:namespaces>
</xml-module:namespace-directory>

<flow name="xpathWithFullNs">
    <xml-module:xpath-extract
      xpath="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/mule:echo/mule:echo"
      namespaceDirectory="fullNs"/> 
</flow>
```

Comment: The example of configuring namespaces in the XML Module configuration is not going to work because if you read the documentation for that configuration it says that only the XPath Extract operation uses it: "Allows to globally map prefixes to namespace URIs. On this version, the xpath-extract operation is the only one to consume these mappings". Your question is related to using namespaces in DataWeave scripts. DataWeave will not use it.

Comment: It works in DataWeave Playground. What is the exact error or result you are getting? What version of Mule are you using?

Comment: @aled Locally declaring prefix in dataweave works, I am looking for a solution where I can store all the namespaces in a centralized place and use it in different flows , in dataweave script.

Comment: Please see my questions in the previous comment.

Comment: I am using mule 4, runtime 4.4.0

Comment: What error did you got? You haven't answered that. What is the path of Namespaces.dwl in your project?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am not finding an option to store all the namespaces in a centralized place, with the first approach I mentioned, it is working but it requires to declare the prefixes again in the dataweave , locally. 

I updated the question to make it more understandable.

Comment: I'm asking what is the *error or issue* when you *don't declare the variables locally*. You are not clear on what is the actual issue. "this doesn't work" is not an error, it is not helpful.

Comment: @aled Thanks for pointing out, Initially I got error and I was distracted by this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514220/import-xml-namespace-from-custom-dataweave-module  , 
and assumed it does not work, tried this again and after fixing minor issue, this works fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

After fixing minor errors, the first approach worked.

Created a custom module and declared namespaces and imported it into my dataweave worked without declaring prefixes again in the local dataweave.

Created below module under the folder src/main/resources/modules

**Namespaces.dwl**

```
ns myNs1 http://namespaces/my1
ns myNs2 http://namespaces/my2
```

**Dataweave :**

```
%dw 2.0
import * from modules::Namespaces
output application/java
---
{
    body: {
        myNs1#Response: {
            outcome: 'ACCEPTED'
        }
    } write "application/xml"
}
```

Comment: You should mention that the Namespaces.dwl file is in the directory src/main/resources/modules. Other people may use different directories and get confused by the reference to `modules`>